# How to convert code to write data in xlsx instead of csv using python without pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, xlsx

I have written a python code to store data in csv format but now need to store in .xlsx file.
how to convert the below code and write the output in .xlsx file.

```
  details_file = self.get_local_storage_path() + '/Myfile.xlsx'
  csv_columns = (
        'id', 'name', 'place', 'salary', 'email',
          )

   with open(details_file, 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(
                csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns, extrasaction='ignore')
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in details:
                writer.writerow(data)
```

#I tried as below but getting error as
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'

```
with open(details_file, 'w') as csvfile:           
            print("inside open")
            workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(csvfile)
            worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
            print("before for loop")
            for data in details:
                worksheet.write(data)
            workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) for this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(csv_columns, details)))

# save to csv:
df.to_csv(path, index=False)

#save to xlsx:
df.to_excel(path, index=False)
```

You might need to install `openpyxl` for the last line to work.

But if you really need to use `xlsxwriter` for this, here's how I would do it based on their [tutorial](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html):

```py
import xlsxwriter

csv_columns = (
    'id', 'name', 'place', 'salary', 'email',
)
details = [
    [1, 'A', 'B', 2, 'c@d.com'],
    [3, 'C', 'D', 4, 'e@f.com'],
]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for col, name in enumerate(csv_columns):
    worksheet.write(0, col, name)

for row, det in enumerate(details, 1):
    for col, value in enumerate(det):
        worksheet.write(row, col, value)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, but without pandas, I need to try

Comment: any help without pandas?

Comment: @Mia I updated the answer with an example using `xlsxwriter`

Comment: @Maz, Thanks but the output is like all rows and columns filled with csv_columns only not details. Any idea on how to solve this ? please

Comment: @Mia did you try to copy-paste and run my code to see if works?

Comment: sorry my data is in different format corrected the code thanks for your help!